# Derby Database with Date Format alfa + numeric

Tags: derby

In storing my date in a derby table as "Apr 5 2017" (alpha  + numeric) , will the query code here know how to query properly? As opposed to an all numeric format "04 05 2017". In other words, Can the query handle charvar for month sorting?

```java
 (PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from TEST5 where startCol >= date1 and endCol <= date2" ); 
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()) {
      MainDisplay.jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

      rs.close();
      st.close();
      con.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, if you store the date in the db as a string like this the sorting will just be a string compare and the order will not be correct (how is Derby supposed to know this is a date?).

You should define the column type as being a `DATE` if you want it to hold a date or `TIMESTAMP` for a date + time.

Comment: To expand on your answer somewhat, what's important is the database column's type, not the type of data in the program which stores the data into the database. Using Java's utility classes, you can convert data from a variety of input formats into a variety of database column types, and dates and times should be converted from string representations into internal `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` types at the time of the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Thank-you!  :  )   I desire the query results be in the more friendly format ie: "Apr 03 2017" as to "04 03 2017   ...... so I would need to do some kind of a look up table?     .... ie:  APR = 04;

Comment: You store the date in the database using DATE or TIMESTAMP and you format the date in the Java code using something like DateTimeFormatter or SimpleDateFormat. You do **not** store dates as string in the database.